# Smooth shading and N-gons troubles

Tags: shaders

I'm trying to make a cup.
Problem is where the handle meets the cup, the smooth shading is not giving correct results.
[image] [image]

I have read that this is usually caused by N-gons, like the ones where the handle meets the cup with different mesh number.
I have tried to get rid of them by triangles and wiggling them around, but it does not change anything.
[image][image]

Basically the questions is how to solve this situation? I guess it happens every time a "detailed" part meets a flat part so that must be quite common.

Comment: why do you have too much geometry on the handle as compared to the cup? does adding a *subdivision surface* modifier mitigate the problem?

Comment: I made the handle by extruding an ellipse along a path because it's a weird shape. The result gave me super dense meshes so I already dissolved tons to get to what you see here. Subdivision surface doesn't really help, I guess it's just my way of doing things that is wrong here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have ngons, on round surfaces it can create shading problems. As Harry says, you don't need so many vertices to create the handle, 8 vertices are enough (even 6 are enough):

[image]

[image]

Flatter shape with sharper edges on the side:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, looks good however the actual cup handle is a flat-ish ellipse, if I make it with only 8/6 vertices I get super sharp edges near the focus points, any advice on how to solve this?

Comment: See my edit, is it what you want?

Comment: dumb me was placing a single edge right at the peak of the curve, making it super sharp. Thank you for showing the proper way.